# How to enable specific if-else formatting in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

I want to get this format by default. I wonder if there are any settings in Visual Studio? I searched, but I didn't find anything.

```
if {
    
} else if {
    
} else if {
    
} else if {
 
} else {
    
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can definitely configure MSVS to format your code with that indentation style.  For example, MSVS > Tools >  Editor  > Code Style. Look here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019

Comment: Which "Visual Studio" are you talking about? The MS Visual Studio IDE, or Visual Studio Code?  Please add the appropriate "tag" to your post.

Answer (score 0):

EASY.
Install Prettier from marketplace and set it as default format tool then press shift+alt+f to see your code in proper identation.
You can also install ident-rainbow to help you with this while you are writing your code!

Comment: link? AFAIK, Prettier is a JavaScript formatter whereas this question is tagged with C++

Comment: It's unclear if the OP is referring to MS Visual Studio ("MSVS", the compiler IDE) or Visual Studio Code ("VSCode", the code editor).  If MSVS, you should be able to configure editor preferences directly - no 3rd-party add-ons are needed.  If VSCode, the C/C++ extension also supports code formatting: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 17 or better (suppose you do)

Check out the formatter VS is using, https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

You will find a reference to install the extension here,

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format

It will accept a configuration file for clangformat.